# Why does this text sometimes render incorrectly in Paper.js in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, paperjs

For the included example, sometimes quotes render fine, sometimes they appear as boxes, and sometimes nothing appears at all.

Some problem text includes:

- (TPI 1)
- "Delegated or Specialty Engineer"

"Delegated Engineering Documents" seems to always work

I have noticed inconsistent behavior with things like degree symbols too.

Thank you in advance!

[JSON File link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83bq1gSkUdqaWpudGU0Qnh5cWs/view?usp=sharing)

```
[["PointText",{"applyMatrix":false,"matrix":[1,0,0,1,21.82495,346.73207],"selected":true,"content":"The TDDs herein are specialty structural component designs and may be part of the Building's deferred or phased submittal documents. As a Truss Design \nEngineer (also referred to in some Jurisdictions as a Delegated or Specialty Engineer), the seal on this Cover Sheet and on any TDD represents an acceptance of\nprofessional engineering responsibility for the design of the single Truss only as depicted on the TDD pursuant to ANSI/TPI 1, the National Design Standard for \nMetal Plate Connected Wood Truss Construction (TPI 1). The Building Designer is responsible for and shall coordinate and review each of the TDDs and all notes \nfor compatibility with the Construction Documents, specifications, written requirements, design loads and load path. Capitalized terms are as defined in TPI 1. \n\n","selectedColor":[0,0.50196,0],"fontSize":"18","leading":18},{"pdfPosition":["Point",126.82495,985.76793],"centerPositionInPdfCoordinates":["Point",773.15503,1048.76793],"centerPositionInRasterCoordinates":["Point",8.15503,-58.76793],"userEmail":"foo@bar.com","fontSizeInPoints":7.2,"bottomLeftPositionInRasterCoordinates":["Point",-638.17505,4.23207]}],["PointText",{"applyMatrix":false,"matrix":[1,0,0,1,24.8473,260.1569],"selected":true,"content":"The TDD(s) (also at times referred to as \"Delegated Engineering Documents\") referenced have been prepared based on the Construction Documents, \nspecifications and written requirements prepared by the Building Designer indicating the nature and character of the Building, its applied load, its load paths and \nthe structural resistance design requirements. The design criteria from the Construction Documents, specifications and written requirements have been transferred \nto DrJ Engineering, LLC (DrJ) by","selectedColor":[0,0.50196,0],"fontSize":"18","leading":18},{"pdfPosition":["Point",129.8473,1126.3431],"centerPositionInPdfCoordinates":["Point",778.66029,1162.3431],"centerPositionInRasterCoordinates":["Point",13.66029,-172.3431],"userEmail":"foo@bar.com","fontSizeInPoints":7.2,"bottomLeftPositionInRasterCoordinates":["Point",-635.1527,-136.3431]}]]
```